# Android and SSL - checking certificate validity

Tags: android

I've got the following code making SSL work with my HttpClient connections and such

```
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", 
            SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));

HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, params);
```

However, does this actually validate the cert?  It seems like there should be more to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, the above code does indeed validate the certificate.  I tried it with some random self signed certs for different sites, and it failed.